# Grails - select tag

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a question, I believe it is quite simple. I Have googled, books, etc., but could not solve my problem.

The thing is, I have a domain called "Group" and another domain called "Rules". One group can have several Rules, so I the group domain class:

```
class Grupo {
  String nome

  static hasMany = [rules: Rules]

  static mapping = {
      rules cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  }
}
```

The domain Rules only have one attribute called "nome"

And in my gsp I did as follows:

```
<g:select
   class="form-control"
   name="grupo.rules"
   from="${iquem.Rules.list()}"
   multiple="multiple"
   optionValue="nome"
/>
```

But if I do `println grupo?.rules` at my controller I always receive null

Please someone could help me?

Comment: in your controller do params.each { key,val -> println "$key : $val"} and see what parameters you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

Cause you set multiple attribute of select to: multiple="multiple", if you do a form submission to your controller the name of params is not grupo.rules but grupo.rules[] cause it's an array of multiple values.

Else if you do not perform a form submit and you do something like :

```
grupo = Grupo.findByNome("Anome")
```

and after you do println grupo?.rules and you recive null the reason can be:

1. grupo is null -> your find don't match anything in your persistence layer
2. grupo don't have any child in rule

Hope this help, bye.

Comment: I could figure out what the was problem!

Grails to be able to convert automatically to the relationship entity, you have to mandatory pass the id in optionKey, being as follows:

    <g:select
      class="form-control"
      name="grupo.rules"
      from="${iquem.Rules.list()}"
      multiple="multiple"
      optionKey="id"
      optionValue="nome"/>